# What is a relationship between sets and Factorials of Non-Natural number?

Tags: relations, gamma-function, natural-numbers

We know that factorial of natural number n describes how many bijections there are from some set with k cardinality into itself.
But what if cardinality of the set is non natural number? or what if the set is uncountable?

if factorial of non natural number n is $$n!=\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x}x^{n}\:dx}$$
and n describes cardinality of some set, then waht is this result for the set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral-defined function's domain is the real numbers greater than $-1$. But non-natural real numbers can't even *be* cardinalities of sets -- what does it mean for a set to have $\frac{1}{2}$ an element in it? So, then, it's not meaningful to ask "how many permutations of a set containing $\frac{1}{2}$ elements are there?", because there isn't even any meaning to such a set.

Answer (score 2):

What you actually use is the technique of analytic continuation, where a function defined on a subset of the complex plane (the integers here) is extended into an analytic function in a domain that is as large as possible; in this case the whole complex plane without the negative x-axis. But then, AFAIK, the meaning of $n!$ as , say,the number of orderings for {$1,2,..,n$} is lost when you extend beyond the natural numbers.

Comment: I am not an expert by any means but am pretty sure this is not analytic continuation...

Comment: The shifted Gamma function is **not** obtained from the factorial function by analytic continuation. In fact there is no (unique) way to associate an analytic function to the factorial function.

Comment: But, isn't the restriction of the Gamma function to the positive integers equal to the factorial function?

Comment: The function $\Gamma(z)=\Integral t^ze^{-t} \frac{dt}{t} $ restricts to n! on the non-negative integers. The extension is not unique, but it is an extension nonetheless.